# How to avoid iteration inside an array based function in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

Supose I have, in numpy, a matrix multiplication function parameterized by 2 variables `x` and `y`:

```
import numpy as np

def func(x, y):
    a = np.array([[1, x],
                  [x, 2]])
    b = np.array([[y,         2*x],
                  [x, np.exp(y+x)]])
    M = np.array([[3.2, 2*1j],
                  [4  ,   93]])

    prod  = a @ M @ b
    final = np.abs(prod[0,0])

    return final
```

I can run this function easily for any two numerical values, e.g. `func(1.1, 2.2)` returns `129.26...`.

So far so good, but now I want to run this for several values of `x` and `y`, e.g. `x=np.linspace(0,10,500)` and `y=np.linspace(0,10,500)`. I want to pair these 500 values in a one-to-one correspondence, that is the first one in the `x` list with the first one in the `y` list, the second one with the second one, etc.

I can do that by adding a `for` loop inside the function but the procedure becomes extremely slow in my actual code (which is more computationally demanding than this example here). What I would like to ask for support is **how to do this faster with only numpy functions?** Is that what the numpy `ufunc`'s meant for? I've never looked into it.

Comment: Do you know how to make a (500,2,2) shape array from `x`?  The `@` can handle 3d arrays like that, treating the dimension as a 'batch'.

Comment: "I've never looked into it.". You really should look into things before asking. Do your own research please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vectorization is pretty direct, as long as you keep track of dimensions. In fact, you can be completely agnostic to the sizes of `x` and `y` as long as they broadcast together. The solution shown here will return  something that has that same broadcasted shape:

```
def func(x, y):
    x = np.array(x, copy=False)
    y = np.array(y, copy=False)
    bc = np.broadcast(x, y)

    a = np.stack((np.ones_like(x), x, x, np.full_like(x, 2)), axis=-1).reshape(*x.shape, 2, 2)
    b = np.stack((np.broadcast_to(y, bc.shape),
                  np.broadcast_to(2 * x, bc.shape),
                  np.broadcast_to(x, bc.shape),
                  np.exp(y + x)), axis=-1).reshape(*bc.shape, 2, 2)
    M = np.array([[3.2, 2*1j],
                  [4  ,   93]])

    prod  = a @ M @ b
    final = np.abs(prod[..., 0, 0])

    return final
```

Keeping the matrices in the last two dimensions ensures that your matrix multiplication works normally. Stacking is multidimensional equivalent to the concatenation you are doing with `np.array` and scalars.

```
>>> func(1.1, 1.1)
120.9100165412279
>>> func(1.1, 2.2)
129.26872205
>>> func(2.2, 1.1)
463.34089222
>>> func(1.1, [1.1, 2.2])
array([120.91001654, 129.26872205])
>>> func([1.1, 2.2], 1.1)
array([120.91001654, 463.34089222])
>>> func([1.1, 2.2], [2.2, 1.1])
array([129.26872205, 463.34089222])
```

Notice the identical behavior for scalars.